# Bilinear maps on Hilbert spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Is there any characterization of continuous bilinear maps $m:H_1\times H_2\to \mathbb C$ , where $H_1,H_2$ are Hilbert spaces? I have read somewhere that such bilinear maps are of kind $m(a,b)=\left< Ta,b\right>$ for some $T\in B(H_1,H_2)$ but it looks like to me a sesquilinear form.  I am confused.

Comment: There is no reason why a bilinear map is continuous.

Comment: Yes i am considering only continuous ones here.

Comment: You are right. $\langle Tx, y\rangle$ is bilinear in the case of real scalars but not in the case of complex scalars.

Comment: Working over $\Bbb C$, one sometimes abuses terminology and say 'bilinear' for 'sesquilinear'.